# One of my daytime running lights don’t work In the day time but in the night time it turns on

Tags: chevrolet, lights, camaro, daytime-running-lights

I have a 2017 Camaro and one my DRL doesn’t light up in the day but works in the night time perfectly fine. Also if I switch my lights to Manual they both turn on but the bad one isn’t as bright

Answer (score 0):

I would first try swapping the lamps over temporarily and see if the issue moves with the lamp.

You won’t be able to fit them in place, but you should be able to plug them into the harness.

If the issue moves with the lamp, you will need another lamp.

Report back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes those newer "strip" style DRLs are fed from a single light source and the brightness is moderated, and sometimes they are fed with two different light sources (i.e. one bulb for "DRL" brightness and another bulb "marker light" brightness.  Look at your wiring diagram or bulb replacement guide in the owner's manual for clues.  If it lists a bulb replacement for the DRL, that'll be your clue that you'll be able to fix this easily.

Does your Camaro have standard Halogen headlights or Xenon?  I don't have one here, but it looks to me from the parts diagram that the DRL strip in the Halogen headlamp assembly is just a plastic reflector that is backlit by a regular bulb in a socket.  In that case, you'd just need to find the bulb and replace it.

If you have the Xenon headlights, it looks like the DRL strip is an integral LED assembly that is permanently installed in the housing itself.  In this case, your options for repairing it are to replace the entire headlamp assembly, or carefully take the headlamp apart and replace the DRL LED boards.

For a better idea of what is in there and how it fits together, look online for companies that sell the color changing kits for LED DRLs.  They usually include installation videos that can give you a good look at the "guts" of your lighting assembly before you start deciding to replace or repair.